# Oracle ODBC: DB on Windows Server 2003 – Windows 7 Client Connection Problems

Tags: windows, oracle, odbc

I have an Oracle DB on a Win 2k3 Server (64-Bit).  I have to access the database from a Win7 (64-Bit) machine.

I have downloaded Instant Client and the 64-Bit ODBC driver, and have apparently successfull installed it.  Specifically, I downloaded the Instant Client and driver zip files, unzipped them both to the same directory, then ran the odbc_install.exe file.  This reported driver installed successfully.  Then I added the directory to the windows "Path" environment variable.  (i.e., I followed the instructions [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-100365.html)).

The problem arises when I attempt to connect.  I open the ODBC Data Source Administrator, attempt to add a System DSN.  When I click on "Test Connection", the bastard hangs and crashes.  It doesn't matter what details I try an put in there, it hangs and crashes.

Comment: It could be helpful to know what the DSN setting you are using, but even without that are you using the 32 or 64 bit ODBC admin tool to create your DSN?